# UIView fill animation in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I want to fill the color of view from left to right as fill animation. I have been using this code to get the effect but somehow it doesn't show any animation.i am using below code.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0.2, options:.curveLinear, animations: {
                view!.backgroundColor = Constant.AppColor.viewBottomFocus
            }, completion:nil)
```

please tell me how can i achieve this?

Comment: this view you have created in storyboard ? or you drawer programatically ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can fill a color with left to right animation with simple UIView blocks. You can ofcourse change width or trailing constraint of the view and it will appear that the view is changing its color. But, I dont think thats the ideal way to do it.

To achieve what you want I guess you have to use gradient layer and animate the locations:

```
class AnimatingV:UIView {

    func animate() {
        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        let startLocations = [0, 0]
        let endLocations = [1, 2]

        layer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
        layer.frame = self.frame
        layer.locations = startLocations as [NSNumber]
        layer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0)
        layer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)

        let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        anim.fromValue = startLocations
        anim.toValue = endLocations
        anim.duration = 2.0
        layer.add(anim, forKey: "loc")
        layer.locations = endLocations as [NSNumber]
    }
}

let animatingV = AnimatingV(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
animatingV.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
animatingV.animate()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = animatingV
```

[image]

Comment: Please tell me a better way fo doing it.I am not able to do it ?

Comment: @DhirajKumar: I dont know any other "better" way.

Answer (score 1):

Create **UIView** in storyboard and make its subclass of **UIProgressView**
then use this code to fill view , you can use animated fill as well by calling this function in scheduler

```
//progressView is view that you have create in storyboard

progressView.progress = .25; // .25 is the fill rate of total view
progressView.trackTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Comment: This does not animate though it is filling the color

Comment: Call this changes in scheduler I mentioned in my ans , and pass incremental percentage there , then you will see animated fill

Comment: I can't use this approach because i have some inital color of uiview